# Precision issue of dividend adjustment

Tags: dividends, adjustments

I'm having an issue with calculation of dividend adjusted prices as I have some mismatches with adjusted prices on other data sources.

For example, here is a day when dividend ex_date of IBM happened:

```
2023-08-09
Close (as traded) - 142.49
Dividend - 1.66
```

Previous day:

```
2023-08-08
Close (as traded) - 145.91
```

As far as I understand, to calculate the adjusted price for the last+ days I need to find a ratio *(Close - Dividend) / Close* and then multiple previous prices by this ratio. Then the dividend adjusted close for the previous day (2023-08-08) is (142.49 - 1.66) / 142.49 * 145.91 = 144.2101572. However, on one data source it is 144.229732223378 and on another 144.250000. All 3 values differ.

When I check the adjustment value for even earlier date (sure, many dividend incomings took place then and all are taken into account) I see even bigger difference:

1999-11-01

```
My adjusted close: 52.20542055
Data source 1: 51.3507870764708
Data source 2: 51.407772
```

I see that the difference is even bigger. Is there is an issue with my calculation (see the formula I use above) or just some precision issue (like floats are treated differently on different platforms)? Split adjustment values are all similar - the issue is only with dividends.